# Primefaces eclipse designer

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

i was wondering if there's a Primefaces eclipse designer released yet or expected to be released soon, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the reply of the  PrimeFaces Lead at [this](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15567&p=47460&hilit=eclipse%20plugin#p47460) and [this](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3421&p=15697&hilit=eclipse%20plugin#p15697) , I think there are no visual designers for the Primefaces now.

Comment: Hi. Are there any primefaces visual designers available today?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a specific Primefaces designer. If there is some JSF designer around it should also work with primefaces but I don't know a JSF designer either.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss folks have a bundle of plugins for eclipse called [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools), you can find a JSF visual editor there, it's kinda limited but I think it is as close as you can be from a full designer. Also, JBoss Tools is awesome :)